# Issue With Excel Template Files

Tags: excel

I have been using Microsoft Excel 2003 since it first came out and am only just coming across an apparent problem with it.  I have a number of .xlt files that are used throughout the company and have never had any issues with them.  However, it has just come to light that there is a user who can change the template.

Ordinarily you open the Template file (e.g. Template.xlt) and on opening it find it is called Template1.  On pressing the save icon you are taken to the the Save As screen with the default option to save the file as Template1.xls in MyDocuments (Default location).

In this one case though, the user opens the file as Template, and on pressing the save icon overwrites the original .xlt file.  I have never seen this before and am bamboozled.  Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not the best form to answer your own questions, but hopefully someone else will be able to benefit from the solution that I have found.

In order to solve this, download and install a program named FileTypesMan.

Run the program and find the .xlt extension.  In an ordinary working system this will have at least New and Open as options with New set to default.  In this case there was only Open as an option.  Create an option for New and set this to default.....Presto, sorted.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly does the user open the template?

If a template is opened by double clicking the .xlt (or .xltx/.xltm) file in Windows Explorer, the template generates a new Excel file based on the template.

If an .xlt (or .xltx/.xltm) is right-clicked in Windows Explorer and then the "Open" command is selected in the context menu, then the template file itself will be opened.

If an .xlt (or .xltx/.xltm) template file is opened via Excel's File > Open dialog, the template file itself is opened.

A shortcut that leads to an Excel template behaves in this way:

- double-click - creates a new file based on the template.
- right-click > New - creates a new file based on the template.
- right-click > Open - opens the template itself.

Edit: if the behaviour of double clicking a template file (or a link to a template) occurs only for one user, you may want to unregister and re-register Excel 2003.

Quoting from [this question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-customize/excel-2003-template-opening-as-xlt-instead-of-as/ea15cb4e-8b77-4d62-b3fd-8759b4f0a3d2) at the Microsoft Answers forum:

```
> Start>Run>excel /unregserver
> - note the space between excel and /unregserver then 
> Start>Run>excel /regserver
> - again note the space between excel and /regserver
```

Comment: The file is opened via double clicking on a desktop shortcut which links to the file on the server.  This is the same for all users across the network.

Comment: Are you saying that User A double clicks the shortcut and a new file based on the template is created, and User B double clicks the shortcut and the template itself is opened? Can you check what the two shortcuts link to?

Comment: This is correct.  The only difference with the shortcuts are the initial letters to which the server drive is mapped to.

Comment: Do the users have identical permissions to the respective drives? I just edited my answer to include the shortcut behaviour. I cannot recreate the "double-click opens template file" behaviour. Please verify that the user does not use right-click > Open.

Comment: Added more info to answer

Comment: The users do have identical permissions.  The only think that I can think of is that somehow they have changed the system so when they double click it opens via the context menu?

Comment: Yes, I have just tried that and unfortunately this doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: What else have you tried? User logging on to a different machine? Other users logging on to that user's machine? Does the problem follow the user, i.e. user profile problem? Or is it on the hardware?

Comment: The user has logged on to another machine and the template opens correctly.  I have logged on to his machine and the template opens correctly.  It appears to be a single user issue on a single machine.  However, it is a problem on ALL templates in that instance.

Comment: Uninstall/re-install Office.

Comment: Not sure how this would help given that a different user can open templates without issue on the same install of office.

Comment: Well, if it's only for THAT user on THAT machine, delete the user profile and create a new profile for THAT user.