# .xltm file opens as .xlsx file in Excel

Tags: c#

I am facing the issue while opening an Excel macro-enabled template(.xltm) file when I open from my application.

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850650/issue-with-excel-template-files) which tells how the .xltm file opens. Here I want to override the orignal .xltm file so I need to open the same in .xltm format programatically in c#.

Below is code used to call the Workbooks.Open.

`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Open(DisplayFile, false, false, Type.Missing, "", "",Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 0)`

However, it opens the file in Excel in .xlsx format only.

Need suggestions on what needs to be changed in calling the 'Workbooks.Open' method or any other method can be used.

I have also posted this question in Stack Overflow but got to know that Super User is more appropriate place to have your questions answered relevant to Excel.

Comment: This is obviously a programming question. Also, use named parameters and skip all that `Type.Missing`.

Comment: If you were doing this within Excel, this would be the site.  Pretty much everything C# belongs on Stack Overflow (hover on the tag).  In general though, please don't cross post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after posting the same question on many places I got the answer !! Just need to set argument `editable` to `True` in the `Workbooks.Open` method.